# DZone promotes "ITQuestions", a StackOverflow ripoff

Tags: discussion, copyright-infringement

```
http://www.dzone.com/
http://itquestions.com/
```

Comment: And SO ripped off from forums, reddit and wikipedia. Think if no app ripped off from any other, and they would all have different UI elements such as menus, toolbars, shortcuts, mouse gestures, keystroke meanings, etc.

Comment: @Kop true, but SO didn't scape the forums content then post it on a site with a similar look and feel

Comment: Do they obey SO's creative commons license?

Comment: @Kop Oh hush. Stack Overflow is very different from Reddit and Wikipedia.

Comment: That's interesting as on the "About us" page (http://stackoverflow.com/about) it says that Stack Overflow is based on those. I don't understand people who don't like software inspired by some other successful software.. Not doing it would extremely harm technological progress.

Comment: "synthesize aspects of" is not the same as "rip off"; Stack Overflow serves a unique purpose whereas its clones do not. Reddit is a candidate for ripping off Digg, but at least its site organization is different.

Comment: @mcandre that's all true on an ethical level, but what do you want to do about it? As long as those sites obey the rules of the CC license, there is nothing one can do.

Answer (score 2):

This framework actually draws from SO:
http://www.osqa.net/

Comment: "rip off" is a bit strong: It's one of the many officially acknowledged and even somewhat encouraged [Open-Source SO clones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) that at the same time offers hosting for the system.

Comment: Not any more than OpenOffice ripped off Microsoft Office, not any more than Gimp ripped off Photoshop, not any more than Android ripped off Iphone - they just created an open source version with similar features. This is not a bad thing.

Comment: Just because you happen to be first at something doesn't mean you are going to win at it.

Comment: Site-specific SOs are fine, with attribution of course. I've seen plenty of sites that scrape SO; I assumed this was one of them.